# How to create a new local repository in UFT

Tags: hp-uft

How to create a new local repository in UFT.

go to the path where your uft project is present
you will see one folder with project name having action0 & action1
action0 is  default for global properties
action1 having .bdb file called or means local object repository file.
just create a same file with same name using .bdb extension and delete the old one
now import the project on your machine

Comment: Not a question, should be removed